# Phonegap/Cordova Cannot be resolved to a type... Whenever eclipse want

Tags: cordova

I'm creating phonegap mobile web applications and the problem is, sometimes eclipse finds all the files that it needs, i.e. the JAR libraries and other cordova libraries.. but let's imagine i make a clean and build.. or a refresh and there BOOM... 60ish errors of "cannot be resolved to a type", eclipse doesn't find anything anymore.
It's okay ! I'll rebuild it ! BOOM again, everything works... it's the end of the work day in France and i've spent the entire day on the refresh/clean & build buttons in eclipse so i'm asking, has anybody seen something like that ?
Thank you for your time !

Comment: No, sorry, never seen that. Perhaps you can give a more concrete description of the problem, e.g. paste the first or the last relevant error message in your question, tell something about the project you're working on and post the code that causes the first error that is detected.

Comment: Do you always add the two projects in eclipse (the project and cordova-lib project)? And also, do you really need eclipse? (I've gained in productivity since I used cmd scripts instead of eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you build CordovaLib before you build your actual project.  This is because we made a change so that the framework is now a dependency so that it's easier to advanced users to debug, and works like other common Android libraries.

I would recommend only running a clean on your project, and not the CordovaLib.  The only time you should clean CordovaLib and rebuild it is when you're upgrading Cordova.

Also, you may want to turn auto-build off on Eclipse.  That "feature" drives me nuts, since it fails so often.